# Insert three horizontal lines in my graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I insert three lines in my graph (I'll insert an image for you to see). These horizontal lines refer to my obtained mean, mean - standard deviation and the other mean + standard deviation. Executable code below:

```
df <- structure(
  list(Update = c("2021-08-21","2021-08-21","2021-08-21","2021-08-21","2021-08-21","2021-08-21","2021-08-21",
                  "2021-08-21","2021-08-21","2021-08-21","2021-08-21","2021-08-21","2021-08-21","2021-08-21","2021-08-21",
                  "2021-08-21","2021-08-21","2021-08-21","2021-08-21","2021-08-21"), 
       Busy = c("2021-02-04","2021-01-07","2021-01-11","2021-01-21","2021-06-01","2021-03-01","2021-04-01",
                "2021-08-03","2021-04-02","2021-07-02","2021-06-02","2021-05-02","2021-05-12","2021-07-12","2021-07-18",
                "2021-07-22","2021-07-10","2021-07-11","2021-03-12","2021-04-12"),
       D1 = c(5,3,4,5,6,3,4,4,2,3,4,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,3,4), DR1= c(2,4,5,8,9,3,4,4,3,2,3,1,5,4,3,5,6,5,4,3),
       DR2 = c(4,2,5,5,3,3,3,7,3,5,2,2,2,3,5,6,8,12,4,5), DR3  = c(2,2,3,6,7,5,2,2,2,1,6,8,2,5,2,4,5,6,7,11),
       DR004  = c(3,5,6,3,4,5,1,3,2,1,2,7,5,6,12,3,4,5,6,7), DR5 = c(4,5,6,6,7,2,1,3,2,4,8,5,4,5,3,4,5,6,7,5), 
       DR6 = c(4,5,5,6,3,3,1,3,2,2,5,2,2,3,4,5,7,5,4,3)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))


historic<-subset(df,df$Busy<df$Update) 

average<-mean(historic$D1) 
standard<-sd(historic$D1)
evol<-subset(df,df$Busy<df$Update) 
median_ocup<-sapply(evol[startsWith(names(evol), "DR")], median)
plot(median_ocup[1:10],xlab="Days",ylab="Number")
```

[image]

I would like to insert lines like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `abline` but you'd also need to adjust the limits on the y-axis.

```
line_vals<-c(average-standard, average, average+standard)
abline(h=line_vals, col="red",lwd=5)
```

You could also add text if required.

```
text(10, line_vals+0.2, c("Mean - Standard Deviation", "Mean", "Mean + Standard Deviation"), pos=2, cex=0.75, col='red')
```

[image]